# Connecting to SQL Azure without credentials?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

2 questions:

Are there ways to connect to SQL Azure from SSMS without passing in
    any credentials? Similar to how we can connect to an on-prem SQL
    instance via Windows authentication.

If I have a Azure web app, can I connect to my Azure SQL without
    passing the credentials through the connection string? Just like how
    I can set `Integrated Security = True` when connecting to an on-prem
    SQL database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use integrated security.  Currently, Active Directory authentication (integrated security) is available in preview for SQL Database V12.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/

Comment: In the article it says "SQL Server 2016 Management Studio and SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015 support Azure Active Directory authentication" I'm assuming I can't use Azure AD authentication for SSMS 2014 and below? What about connecting to my Azure SQL from a web app?

Answer (score 3):

--I'm assuming I can't use Azure AD authentication for SSMS 2014 and below?
--What about connecting to my Azure SQL from a web app?

Hello Jack-

This is correct, only SQL 2016 tools are supported.
In case of programming interface you need VS2015, .Net 4.6 or higher and ADALSQL.DLL . All is documented in the mains MSDN article mentioned above.
Feel free to contact SQLAzureADAuth@microsoft.com alias for further questions.
Thanks,
Mirek

Mirek Sztajno, Senior Program Manager SQL Server security team